# Radius and interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ by root and ratio test are different?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

By using ratio test

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{(2(n+1))!}\frac{(2n)!}{x^{2n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}=0$$

By using root test

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{{(2n)!}^{\frac1n}} = x^2$$

By using root test then the series convergent only when $0<x<1$ while with ratio test x can be any real number. What is the mistake I made here. I assume that (I can't prove it's true) $\lim_{n\to\infty}{{(2n)!}^{\frac1n}}=1$. It is the part that I can't make sure as same as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^n}=0$.

Comment: You got two things wrong: 1. You should take the (2n)-th root for the root test. 2. \lim_{n \to \infty} (2n)!^\frac{1}{n}=\infty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(2n)! > 2n(2n-1)\cdots (n+2)(n+1) > n^n \implies [(2n)!]^{1/n} > n$$

Answer (score 0):

[Note that from DeMoivre's formula](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixm65p4rxbxpf82/DeMoivre_formula_and_Striling_formula.pdf?dl=0), we have
$$(2n)! \sim C \sqrt{2n} \left(\dfrac{2n}e\right)^{2n}$$
Hence, we have
$$\left((2n)!\right)^{1/n} \sim C^{1/n} (2n)^{1/2n} \left(\dfrac{2n}e\right)$$
Hence, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left((2n)!\right)^{1/n} = \infty$$